# 5 to 12 V boost converter not boosting

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, boost, prototyping

For my power electronics course, I need to design a basic boost converter that is converting 5 V to 12 V with 0.5 A output current. Below you can see the simulation results. MOSFET is driven by 20 kHz 0.58 duty 5 V square waves. And rest is as it is seen.

I use IRF510 as switch, 1 mH inductor, 220 uF 25V cap. and 25 Ohm load. However when I attempt to the experiment I stuck around 3-4 V output voltage with IL of 200 mA. When I change the load to 1 kOhm I get the output voltage as I desire, yet the current drawn drops to around ~10-15 milliamp as you might guess.

At the bottom you can also see the driving pwm output that is generated by NE555.

**Solution:** *Problem was using a resistor-like inductor, I tried using a coil inductance  (1mH) and got the desired result. Resistor-like inductors get saturated after few 100 milliamps, so be careful checking that.*

[image: boost sim]
[image: pwm output]

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Is that your experimental results don't match your spice simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was using a **resistor-like inductor**, I tried using a **coil inductance (1mH)** and got the desired result. Resistor-like inductors get saturated after few 100 milliamps, so be careful checking that.